# removing number s from math.random

Tags: javascript, arrays

My problem is that I want to have math.random generate a number and then use that number to pick a website from a list of them. But i only want it to cycle through them once. How can I do that?

okay to specify it a bit more I have these websites which I want to have linked with a button that takes a random website from my list. But I want it to only take each website ones.

```
function myFunction() {
        if (Math.floor((Math.random() * 35) + 1)== 1) {
            window.location.href = "Sang1.html";
        }
        if (Math.floor((Math.random() * 35) + 1)== 2) {
            window.location.href = "Sang2.html";
        }
        if (Math.floor((Math.random() * 35) + 1)== 3) {
            window.location.href = "Sang3.html";
        }
        if (Math.floor((Math.random() * 35) + 1)== 4) {
            window.location.href = "Sang4.html";
        }
        if (Math.floor((Math.random() * 35) + 1)== 5) {
            window.location.href = "Sang5.html";
        }
        if (Math.floor((Math.random() * 35) + 1)== 6) {
           window.location.href = "Sang6.html";
        }
        if (Math.floor((Math.random() * 35) + 1)== 7) {
            window.location.href = "Sang7.html";
        }
        if (Math.floor((Math.random() * 35) + 1)== 8) {
            window.location.href = "Sang8.html";
        }
        if (Math.floor((Math.random() * 35) + 1)== 9) {
            window.location.href = "Sang9.html";
        }
        if (Math.floor((Math.random() * 35) + 1)== 10) {
            window.location.href = "Sang10.html";
        }
        if (Math.floor((Math.random() * 35) + 1)== 11) {
            window.location.href = "Sang11.html";
        }
        if (Math.floor((Math.random() * 35) + 1)== 12) {
            window.location.href = "Sang12.html";
        }
        if (Math.floor((Math.random() * 35) + 1)== 13) {
            window.location.href = "Sang13.html";
        }
        if (Math.floor((Math.random() * 35) + 1)== 14) {
            window.location.href = "Sang14.html";
        }
        if (Math.floor((Math.random() * 35) + 1)== 15) {
            window.location.href = "Sang15.html";
        }
        if (Math.floor((Math.random() * 35) + 1)== 16) {
            window.location.href = "Sang16.html";
        }
        if (Math.floor((Math.random() * 35) + 1)== 17) {
            window.location.href = "Sang17.html";
        }
        if (Math.floor((Math.random() * 35) + 1)== 18) {
            window.location.href = "Sang18.html";
        }
        if (Math.floor((Math.random() * 35) + 1)== 19) {
            window.location.href = "Sang19.html";
        }
        if (Math.floor((Math.random() * 35) + 1)== 20) {
            window.location.href = "Sang20.html";
        }
        if (Math.floor((Math.random() * 35) + 1)== 21) {
            window.location.href = "Sang21.html";
        }
        if (Math.floor((Math.random() * 35) + 1)== 22) {
            window.location.href = "Sang22.html";
        }
        if (Math.floor((Math.random() * 35) + 1)== 23) {
            window.location.href = "Sang23.html";
        }
        if (Math.floor((Math.random() * 35) + 1)== 24) {
            window.location.href = "Sang24.html";
        }
        if (Math.floor((Math.random() * 35) + 1)== 25) {
            window.location.href = "Sang25.html";
        }
        if (Math.floor((Math.random() * 35) + 1)== 26) {
            window.location.href = "Sang26.html";
        }
            if (Math.floor((Math.random() * 35) + 1)== 27) {
        window.location.href = "Sang27.html";
        }
        if (Math.floor((Math.random() * 35) + 1)== 28) {
            window.location.href = "Sang28.html";
        }
        if (Math.floor((Math.random() * 35) + 1)== 29) {
            window.location.href = "Sang29.html";
        }
        if (Math.floor((Math.random() * 35) + 1)== 30) {
            window.location.href = "Sang30.html";
        }
        if (Math.floor((Math.random() * 35) + 1)== 31) {
            window.location.href = "Sang31.html";
        }
        if (Math.floor((Math.random() * 35) + 1)== 32) {
            window.location.href = "Sang32.html";
        }
        if (Math.floor((Math.random() * 35) + 1)== 33) {
            window.location.href = "Sang33.html";
        }
        if (Math.floor((Math.random() * 35) + 1)== 34) {
            window.location.href = "Sang34.html";
        }
        if (Math.floor((Math.random() * 35) + 1)== 35) {
            window.location.href = "Sang35.html";
        }
        if (Math.floor((Math.random() * 35) + 1)== 36) {
            window.location.href = "Sang36.html";
        }
```

Comment: Store the result of `Math.floor((Math.random() * 35) + 1)` in a variable at the start of the function, then use that in your `if` statements (though there's a much better way to do that).

Comment: Store every number in an array and with every new number check if it's already in the array.

Comment: Cycle through them never works in your case since `window.location.href` will refresh the entire page. May be you can use `localStorate` to maintain the array of sites and visited site array.

Answer (score 6):

Put the URLs of the websites in an array.  Shuffle the array.  Pick the websites from the shuffled array in order.  You will pick every website at most once with no repeats.

Comment: I think the incorrect [tag:java] tag has thrown things off. This looks like it's a JavaScript question, and they're changing page which means they're going to lose that array.

Comment: so how can I do this. I would really appreciate some more specific help

Answer (score 1):

First create an array containing all the URLs

```
var urls = ["Sang1.html", "Sang2.html", "Sang3.html"]; // add all URLs here ...
```

Now randomly pick one from the array

```
var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (urls.length - 1));
var url = urls[randomIndex];
```